# Filter an intermediate model and use it to modify queryset of a model

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, admin

I guess my question can be best explained by an example.

```
class A:  # the model where I am making a ModelAdmin
    # 1-to-1 relationship with class B

class B:
    # some fields

class C:
    # many to many with class B
    # field - foreignKey from class D

class D:
    # 1 to 1 relationship with class User

class User:
```

In my modelAdmin for class A, I have defined the get_queryset:

```
def get_queryset(self, request):
    qs = super().get_queryset(request)
    if request.user.is_superuser:
        return qs
    ??return qs.filter(class_C_field=request.user.class_D.pk)
```

where the ?? means what I want to do is get all the records from the intermediate table generated by B and C and get only those whose field in class C is equal to one of the instances from class D.
After that, I want to use the fields of class C and class B to display in my list_display for the model Class A

Answer (score 0):

```
    def get_queryset(self, request):
    qs = super().get_queryset(request)
    if request.user.is_superuser:
        return qs
    qs = A.objects.filter(Afield__C__Cfield=request.user.D.pk)
    return qs
```

Turns out that I can query it from Class A. So if the user is not an admin, qs returns the list of all records from A that belong to C under a foreign key from D. There was no need for B since A has a one-to-one with B.